# Way to Non-Keep-Alive Connections with Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a demo distributed app that shows how to load balance between many different containers. The app works fine, but I'm trying to force refreshing between different containers, and Chrome/Firefox are keeping the connection open. I thought that forcing the connection to close with .close() would work:

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback

But this causes the server to close. Is there a way to tell Chrome/Firefox not to hold open the connection to a server in Node without closing the server?

Comment: If this is just for testing purposes, then you can restart chrome/firefox between requests.

Comment: Sorry, i meant demo purposes, not testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question.  As far as I know, there is no normal direct way to disable HTTP keep-alive with the built-in HTTP server.  You *might* be able to work around this.  The request object has a `connection` property which will contain the underlying socket.  You could save a reference to the connection and close it after you have called `end()` on the response.  This really isn't a great idea however.  The client can use pipelining, sending multiple requests before the response from a previous one has finished.

The best thing to do is just add this to your response headers:

```
Connection: close
```

This will signal the client not to keep the connection open.

Comment: That sounds right - do you know how to do this in Node?

Comment: @aronchick `res.setHeader('Connection', 'close')`